# error NU1001: The dependency System.Security.Securestring >= 4.0.0 could not be resolved on VSTS

Tags: .net, coreclr, azure-pipelines

I am able to build my project locally, but when i build on VSTS it keep giving me the error `error NU1001: The dependency System.Security.Securestring >= 4.0.0 could not be resolved.` and I cant figure out why.

Here is my project files. Is there anything that is outdated or wrong?

global.json

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "apps" ]
}
```

\src\S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.Gateway.Common\project.json

```
{
  "title": "Common Library for S-Innoations Service Fabric Gateway",
  "version": "1.0.1-*",
  "name": "S-Innovations.ServiceFabric.Gateway.Common",

  "dependencies": {

  },

  "packOptions": {
    "owners": [ "Poul K. Sørensen" ],
    "tags": [ "S-Innovations ServiceFabric Gateway" ]
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "System.Net.Http": "4.1.0",
        "Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services": "0.6.0-preview-01"
      }
    },
    "net452": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services": "2.2.207"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": [
      //"nuget delete -Verbosity detailed -noninteractive -source %USERPROFILE%\\.nuget\\packages %project:name% %project:version%",
      //"nuget delete -Verbosity detailed -noninteractive -source c:\\localpackages %project:name% %project:version%",
      //"dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration% -o ../../artifacts/",
      //"nuget add -Verbosity detailed -NonInteractive -source c:\\localpackages  ../../artifacts/%project:name%.%project:version%.nupkg"
    ]
  }
}
```

also, here is my build log

https://gist.github.com/pksorensen/29315c5631bbe177efc89e38d8434fb4

Comment: Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 0.6.0-preview-01 looks like a very old version. Could you try updating that to a newer version and see if that helps?

Comment: thats not the problem, it works locally. (its the preview for unix which has lower version numbers for some reason. Its handled with a nuget.config and located within the repository)